# Trigger if user scrolls with scroll wheel when no scrollbar is present

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

So, I'm trying to create something that's unique and uses absolute positioning. Along with `overflow:hidden;`, this website wont contain a scrollbar, but I still need to test when the user is using the scroll wheel.

## Attempts

Here is a Code Snippet of my problem.

```js
document.getElementById("main").onscroll=function(){
  console.log("scrolled");
  document.getElementById("scrolled").innerHTML="true";
}
```

```css
#main {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.object {
  width:100%;
  height:75%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="object"></div>
    <div class="object"></div>
    <div class="object">Can't see me.</div>
</div>
(The objects inside are expanding, it's just hidden)<br>
Try scrolling (with scroll wheel) in the div, then look below.<br>
Scroll triggered: <span id="scrolled">false</span>
```

As you can see, no scroll is triggered, that's because there is no scrollbar!  Essentially, I would still like to know if the scroll wheel is being used, I'd also like to know if it's being used upwards or downwards.

## What's my goal?

Basically, I want to create this "dynamic scrolling" type framework behind my website.  So, the container is `overflow:hidden`, but when the scroll wheel is triggered (either up or down) it increments or decrements a varible which is set as `top:(variable)` in JavaScript.

So all in all, I just want something that detects if the scroll wheel is being used so I can fulfil my dynamic scrolling script.

### Things I'm aware of (so you shouldn't mention them to me)

I'm aware that some people have broken scroll wheels, or don't even have one.  So before you mention it.  My solution to that is putting buttons at the bottom (or top) of each slide, which scrolls down or up according.

### Other

The solution should be **pure javascript**, that means no libraries!  Sorry to put you through the struggle, but that's what I need.  The only acception I'll make is if the script is way to long and a library makes it shorter.  Otherwise, no no.

### That's all!

Thanks for reading through, and good luck find a solution!  I'll be furiously trying to find a solution as well.  I'll update this post to let you know if I find any information, or require something different.

Feel free to ask questions in the comments.

Comment: This may help: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Comment: You could possibly use javascripts `onmousewheel` event to find out if it's being used. Then, with simple math you can find out which direction and apply it to animation: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml - I've made a smooth scrolling website that uses this and it feels great!  It's like bringing mac touchpad scrolling to a windows machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the position gradually in reaction on [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel). This event is fired every time the mouse wheel is scrolled. Event properties deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ contains the size of shift in given direction.

Snippet http://jsfiddle.net/07516utp/ shows sensing of scroll deltas of this event.

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel);

function onWheel(event) {
    document.querySelector('#log').innerHTML = 'event: dx=' + event.deltaX + ' dy=' + event.deltaY + ' dz=' + event.deltaZ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but prehaps you could add more content to your answer, like elaborate on `onwheel` and such, then I'll accept.